# Laravel QueryException on Saving Model: Trying to save wrong model

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have two models in my little aplication, a Post model and another called Autovistoria.
Post Model is working just fine, its kind of a Blog.
But while I'm implementing the AutovistoriaController and View, it looks like the Post model are being called, instead of Autovistoria.
So, my routes for autovistoria are:

```
//form for new Autovistoria
Route::get('autovistoria/nova','AutovistoriaController@criar');
// Create new Autovistoria
Route::post('autovistoria/nova','AutovistoriaController@salvar_vistoria');
```

The Controller methods:

```
<?php

namespace monografia\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use monografia\Autovistoria;
use monografia\User;
use Redirect;
use monografia\Http\Requests\AutovistoriaFormRequest;
use monografia\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class AutovistoriaController extends Controller
{
    public function criar(Request $request)
    {
        // Verifica se usuario pode executar vistoria (Usuários)
        if($request->user()->pode_vistoriar())
        {
            return view('autovistoria.nova');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('autovistoria/listar')->withErrors('Você não tem autorização para criar uma vistoria.');
        }
    }
    public function salvar_vistoria(AutovistoriaFormRequest $request)
   {
        $autovistoria = new Autovistoria();
        $autovistoria->endereco = $request->get('endereco');
        $autovistoria->bairro = $request->get('bairro');
        $autovistoria->cep = $request->get('cep');
        $autovistoria->pavimentos = $request->get('pavimentos');
        $autovistoria->autor_id = $request->user()->id;
        $message = 'Vistoria Criada. Você pode iniciá-la quando desejar';
        $autovistoria->save();
        return redirect('autovistoria.nova')->withMessage($message);
    }
}
```

The Form Request:

```
class AutovistoriaFormRequest extends Request {
    /**
     * Determina se usuário pode fazer a postagem.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if($this->user()->pode_vistoriar())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'endereco' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'bairro' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'cep' => 'required',
        ];
    } }
```

The Model:

```
class Autovistoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'autovistoria';
    // Proteje a tabela contra mudanças
    protected $guarded = [];
    // Retorna a instancia do usuário autor da vistoria
    public function autor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('monografia\User','autor_id');
    }
}
```

the view path to save is correctly, and even when i try to create a new model through tinker it works, but when i send through form, it tries to save in database in posts model instead of Autovistoria, leading to

SQL ERROR: QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'endereco' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from posts where endereco = Rua Teste)

Can someone help me?

edit:

My schema:

```
Schema::create('autovistoria', function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('autor_id') -> unsigned() -> default(0);
  $table->foreign('autor_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->string('endereco')->unique();
  $table->integer('pavimentos');
  $table->text('conteudo');
  $table->text('categoria');
  $table->boolean('vistoriado');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

The form.blade

```
<form action="nova" method="post" name="nova-vistoria">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="endereco">Digite o endereço da Edificação:</label>
        <input required="required" value="{{ old('endereco') }}" placeholder="Rua Exemplo, numero 2" type="text" name = "endereco" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="endereco">Bairro onde está situada:</label>
        <input required="required" value="{{ old('bairro') }}" placeholder="Ex: Barra da Tijuca, Botafoto, Copacabana..." type="text" name = "bairro" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="endereco">CEP da edificação (Apenas números):</label>
        <input required="required" value="{{ old('cep') }}" placeholder="21345123" type="text" name = "cep" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pavimentos">Total de pavimentos da edificação:</label>
            <select name = "pavimentos" class="form-control">
                @for($i = 1; $i < 21; $i++)
                    <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>"
                @endfor
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" name='salvar' class="btn btn-success" value = "Salvar"/></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found the problem.

The issue was the migration file. 
I renamed the class(the name was in plural, i took out the s of it, renamed from Autovistorias to Autovistoria), but haven't changed the migration file class name, so it was not working properly.

It worked fine after changing the migration file class name

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the model  this..

```
class Autovistoria extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'autovistoria';
        // Proteje a tabela contra mudanças
       //https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent  Mass Assignment
        protected $guarded = ['id'];
        // Retorna a instancia do usuário autor da vistoria
        public function autor()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('monografia\User','autor_id');
        }
    }
```

I would also verify that the model (table autovistoria) has:
1) id (int autoincrement)
2) I would try to  save the model with dummy data (in the post method) like this...

```
 public function salvar_vistoria(AutovistoriaFormRequest $request)
   {
        $autovistoria = new Autovistoria();
        $autovistoria->endereco = "Dummy data";
        $autovistoria->bairro = "Dummy data");
        $autovistoria->cep = "Dummy data";
        $autovistoria->pavimentos = "Dummy data";
        $autovistoria->autor_id = "user id";
        $message = 'Vistoria Criada. Você pode iniciá-la quando desejar';
        $autovistoria->save();
        return redirect('autovistoria.nova')->withMessage($message);
    }
}
```

If the model **DOES NOT SAVE** correctly there is and error with the model. I would be usefull if you post the migration file for this table or the table sctructure.

Let me know if this helps :)